# width within a directive not changing in IE

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-class

My directive works perfectly in chrome but not in IE8:

```
app.directive('barMax', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            current: '=',
            max: '='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('max', function (newValue) {
                var newContent = '';
                newContent += '<div class="bottom" style="width:{{max*2}}px;">&nbsp;</div><div class="mid" ng-class="{greater: current >= max, less: current < max}" style="width:{{current*2}}px;">&nbsp;</div><div class="top" style="height:17px;"><div style="width:41%;float:left;margin-top:2px;margin-left:2px;"></div><div style="float:left;width:50%;margin-top:2px;"></div></div>';
                element.append($compile(newContent)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

What happens in IE is that... example may previous max:100 and current: 100 then the gray bar would have a width of 100px and the colored bar will have a width of 100px. The color of the colored bar will be green since current is equal to max... and then I updated the scope.changeability to max: 130 and current:90 so I should expect that the gray bar will have a width of 130px and the colored bar should have a width of 90px but the width does not update. The color is correct. The problem is the width because it does not update.

I also added the polyfill

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('bar-max');
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Can you post all the css for the following classes: top, mid, bottom, greater, less. Also, inline styling + interpolation looks pretty hackish to me. I would use the `element.css` function for dynamic css.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesnt allow unfamiliar tags and therefor you may not use directives as tags like . you must use restrict "A" and use it as an attribute in a known html tag. if you dont want the wrapper tag use replace:true like this

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        scope: ...,
        link:...
```

you can see some examples about all that here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=949DC4EDBFFD4738!189&authkey=!ABZCTBTTOCDYGhk